# Admin panel grid view creation in magento with clickable row

Tags: magento-1.7

How to make clickable grid view row in magento admin panel

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the method `getRowUrl` in your grid.
The method should return an url based on the current row.
Here is an example how it's done in the product grid.

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'),
        'id'=>$row->getId())
    );
}
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. This way it will be helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in grid.php file .

```
   public function getRowUrl($row)
   {

      return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));

   }
```